# npm 'websocket' server send message to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

In the code that I inherited is used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) websocket. I read the documentation and did a lot of google search to find how websocketServer can emit message to the client(browser). Here is a code snippet:

```
    var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        httpServer: server,
        autoAcceptConnections: false,
        path:"/async" //This attribute is not in the documentation
    });

  wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept('relay_protocol', request.origin);
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
       ....
       });
     });
```

I wasnt able to find documentation for `connection` object. What propety does it have?

And last, what method to use to send message back to the client?

In general the information given for this module is very poor. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full documentation for this module is [here](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/HEAD/docs/index.md).

From their example (server):

```
connection.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') {
        console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
        connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
    }
    else if (message.type === 'binary') {
        console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
        connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
    }
});
```

So these both sends a message to the client:

```
connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);

connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
```

I hope this helps!

Tip: try out the [socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) module.

Comment: When I use socket.io and pass to its configuration the same server that websocket is using it brakes the websocket itself. I dont know why.

Comment: Socket.IO uses long-polling and websockets if possible. To use only websockets add this configuration: transports: ['websocket']. More: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/